# Prove or disprove: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{2n} - a_n) =0$, then $a_n$ has a limit (not infinity).

Tags: limits, functions

I need to prove if this is true or false.If true then I need to Prove and if false I need to provide an example that disproves the statement.I tried many times but it didnt work.

Note:- Im new so I dont know how to write in the math format so if you know how to 
please tell me

Comment: best way to learn (atleast i learned like that) is to go through the other's questions edits and see how they wrote them , you will grasp if you see more questions , as for your question i am not able to understand , does an mean $a_{n}$ ?

Comment: Third time this question has been asked in the last day. Where is this from?

Comment: yes it means an and I study in Technion,Israel so I think students there asked the same question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_{2^n} = 1$ and $a_k = 0$ otherwise (i.e. when $k \neq 2^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$). The condition is fulfilled but no limit exists, as the sequence oscillates between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that has $a_n$ strictily increasing to $\infty$ with $a_{2n}-a_n \to 0:$ Set $a_1 = 0, a_n =\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k\ln k}, n>1.$